# What's the fastest way to init a NSString from a CString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, malloc

I need to allocate lot's of NSString objects from cStrings (which come that way from a database), as fast as possible. cStringUsingEncoding and the likes are just too slow - about 10-15 times slower compared to allocating a cString.

However, creating a NSString with a NSString is getting pretty close to cString allocation (about 1.2s for 1M allocations). EDIT: Fixed alloc to use a copy of the string.

```
const char *n;
const char *s = "Office für iPad: Steve Ballmer macht Hoffnung";
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
int len = strlen(s);
for (int i = 0; i<10000000; i++) {
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[str copy]];
    s = s;
}
```

cString allocation test (also about 1s for 1M allocations):

```
for (int i = 0; i<10000000; i++) {
    n = malloc(len);
    memccpy((void*)n, s, 0, len) ;
    n = n;
    free(n);
}
```

But as I said, using stringWithCString and the likes is an order of magnitude slower. The fastest I could get was using initWithBytesNoCopy (about 8s, therefore 8 times slower compared to stringWithString):

```
NSString *so = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:(void*)n length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding freeWhenDone:YES];
```

So, is there another magic way to make allocations from cStrings faster? I'd even not rule out to subclass NSString (and yes, I know it's a cluster class).

EDIT: In instruments I see that NSString's call to CFStringUsingByteStream3 is the root issue.

EDIT 2: The root issue is according to instuments __CFFromUTF8. Just looking at the sources [1], this seems indeed to be quite inefficient and handling some legacy cases.

https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.17/CFBuiltinConverters.c?txt

Comment: Note that `-[NSString initWithString]` most probably does *not* create a new object, but just increases the retain count (because `NSString` is immutable). That's why it is so fast.

Comment: I didn't add it to the question, but I've timed allocating NSStrings also with copies of the NSString in the loop. As expected it needs about twice the time. The memory allocation clearly is not the problem, it's some internal implementation detail of NSString which makes it slow to init an NSString from something else than a NSString - most probably inside this CFStringUsingByteStream3

Comment: If you supply a `char *` as UTF-8 then it's going to need to be parsed, or at the very least undergo a linear search, e.g. because its length is unknown. In your C `malloc` test you take the `len` as known. So the two tests are doing very different things.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. getting the length within the malloc loop doesn't change the result (merely 10-100ms within measurement accuracy).

Comment: @benjist but if you're using `strlen` then that's just a search for the terminating NULL to return length in bytes. There's no UTF-8 parsing. Which I'll bet is exactly what `__CFFromUTF8` is doing.

Comment: I never said the comparison is fair - I know of course that UTF8 parsing is a different story. But see: It's about orders of magnitude difference, something that is clearly indicating that the UTF8 parsing is inefficient.

Comment: I didn't analyse entirely all that the __CFFromUTF8 in the linked Apple source file is doing. But for a start, that call to __CFIsLegalUTF8() within the byte loop seems to be there for legacy reasons and looks like it's very inefficient (it's called during each loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, and Brian's answer, I think the problem here is that to create `NSString`s you're having to parse the UTF-8 strings. So the question arises: do you really need to parse them, then?

If parsing-on-demand is an option then I'd suggest you write a proxy that can impersonate `NSString` with an interface along the lines of:

```
@interface BJLazyUTF8String: NSProxy
- (id)initWithBytes:(const char *)bytes length:(size_t)length;
@end
```

So it's not a subclass of `NSString` and it doesn't try to provide any real functionality. Inside the `init` just keep the bytes, e.g. as `_bytes`, doing whatever is correct for your C memory ownership. Then:

```
- (NSString *)bjRealString
{
    // we'd better create the NSString if we haven't already

    if(!_string)
        _string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:_bytes];

    return _string;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    // if this is invoked then someone is trying to
    // make a call to what they think is a string;
    // let's forward that call to a string so that
    // it does what they expect
    [anInvocation setTarget:[self bjRealString]];
    [anInvocation invoke];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
     return [[self bjRealString] methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
}
```

You can then do:

```
NSString *myString = [[BJLazyUTF8String alloc] initWithBytes:... length:...];
```

And subsequently treat `myString` exactly as though it were an `NSString`.

Comment: Great, you nailed it! I take this as correct answer to my problem, because it speeds up the initialization of (what the user thinks) is a string object, until the NSString is actually used. Secondly, this is indeed what I was in need for as well. I'm writing my own ORM for performance reasons I can't use Core-Data (localized indices using ICU + SQLIte, FTS4, BM25 + other custom FTS rankings etc.). In fact this init is required for for entity members. So thanks, you really gave me the solution for the problem that I actually didn't even mention :-)

Comment: That dispatch_once will only run one time in the program (not one time per instance; one time ever). So if you have more than one instance of this, only one of them will initialize `_string`.

Comment: @RobNapier that's what I get for allowing Xcode to autocomplete my call to `dispatch_once` and then just blindly copying it in here. It should be fixed now, and hopefully I've learnt an important lesson.

Comment: @RobNapier: Your right. But it doesn't deserve a downvote. Just fixing this to be a property of the object and it's to me the best solution. Optimizing __CFFromUTF8 would have been my other attempt. But this is for my particular problem the best.

Comment: This seems like a really weird way to solve this problem (and it breaks the contract that the bytes are copied on call to `initWithBytes:length:`.   Instead of using wonky runtime magic, @benjist should keep the original data buffer around and subdivide it into individual `NSString` instances using the `noCopy` path.  The ORM layer can then manage said instances appropriately, including potentially freeing the memory if needed (which this code apparently won't do).

Comment: Note that passing messages to this object will tend to be very slow. You're forcing the slowest objc_msgSend path every time by using `forwardInvocation:` (@bbum will correct me if I'm wrong on that). And you can't dispatch_once this way: "The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static scope. The result of using a predicate with automatic or dynamic storage is undefined."

Comment: @bbum who says it breaks the contract that bytes are copied? I deliberately didn't supply an `init` so that he can do whatever he wants; do a copy, change it to an `initNoCopy`, whatever fits. And this is exactly what `NSProxy` is for, so how is it wonky? Per the documentation: "Subclasses of NSProxy can be used ... for lazy instantiation of objects that are expensive to create."

Comment: @bbum My ORM layer does all that already, question was about speed of initializing / allocationg a lot of objects. Lazy initialization is fine as well. So that's an answer to it. Everyting in my ORM is of a node type that's part of a syntax tree. That value of the entity member class will to the user be a NSString, when the user needs it to be a NSString. Before it's first used as NSString it's quickly initialized during data mapping phase. So it's the perfect fit for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me to not be a fair test.

1. cString allocation test looks to be allocating a byte array and copying data. I can't tell for sure because the variable definitions are not included.
2. NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:str]; is taking an existing NSString (data already in the correct format) and maybe just increments the retain count. Even if a copy is forced the data is still already in the correct encoding and just needs to be copied.
3. [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s]; has to handle the UTF8 encoding and convert from one encoding (UTF8) to the internal NSString/CFString encoding. The method being used (CFStreamUsingByteStream) has support for multiple encodings (UTF8/UTF16/UTF32/others). A specialized UTF8 only method could be faster but that leads to the question of is this really a performance problem or just an exercise.

You can see the source code for [CFStringUsingByteStream3 in this file](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFStringEncodings.c).

Comment: This is the file I just was right now going to add a link for ;). In comments above I mentioned that I also made a test with a copy of the string - with expected results. Your comment about the retain count is valid, first example isn't entirely correct. However: Since the NSString is explicitely allocated using NSUTF8StringEncoding and the inside encoder only __CFFromUTF8 is called, this seems to be the main issue. This method seems immediately on first sight pretty much inefficient.

Comment: In the first example - from the small snippet of code with no variable declarations - that is the best I could guess at.

Comment: I gave you an upvote because your third point is going to the root: it's really about UTF8 conversion rather than allocation. But the question should be, why __CFFromUTF8 is so slow. Looking at the sources it seems to do a lot and probably could be optimized quite a lot also - if the string is known to be a valid UTF8 char array (which should at least be optionally possible to say, because that's just what the init function suggests).

Comment: UTF8 characters can be composed or decomposed, and are sometimes more than a single "character" (multiple chunks, up to 4 if I'm remembering correctly) so likely the "seems to do a lot" is handling cases (like Japanese) where these things happen more often that you don't need or haven't thought about?  UTF8 conversion for low-ascii is really fast :) but not adequate for many uses and CFString has to support *all* use cases.

Comment: @benjist A validation function which tests whether a byte sequence is actually a valid UTF-8  sequence *can* be made very fast. CFString is far away from using the fastest opportunity. Instead it performs elaborate obscure tasks whose meaning is difficult to figure. Possibly, to make performance optimizations ;) IMHO, the way how this string class is implemented is "borderline" - or I do simply not understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Microbenchmarks are a great distraction, but rarely useful.  In this case, though, there is validity.

Assuming, for the moment, that you've actually measured string creation as being a real source of performance issues, then the real problem can be better expressed as *how do I reduce memory bandwidth?* because that is really where your problems lie;  you causing tons and tons of data to be copied into freshly allocated buffers.

As you've discovered, the fastest you can go is to not copy at all.  `initWithBytesNoCopy:...` exists exactly to solve this case.   Thus, you'll want to create a data construct that holds the original string buffer and manages all the `NSString` instances that point to it as one cohesive unit.

Without thinking it through in detail, you could likely encapsulate the raw buffer in an NSData instance, then use associated objects to create a strong reference from your string instances to that `NSData` instance.   That way, the NSData (and associated memory) will be deallocated when the last string is deallocated.

---

With the additional detail that this is for a CoreData-esque ORM layer (and, no, I'm not going to suggest yer doin' it wrong because your description really does sound like you need that level of control), then it would seem that your ORM layer would be the ideal place to manage these strings as described above.

I'd also encourage you to investigate something like FMDB to see if it can provide both the encapsulation you need and the flexibility to add your additional features (and the hooks to make it fast).

Comment: I disagree with: "how do I reduce memory bandwidth?". That's clearly not the root issue here (because creating NSString objects themselve, or NSStrings with NSStrings, or NSStrings with copies of NSStrings just needs as much or less time as expected). Using instruments I see calls to CFStringUsingByteStream3 as the function eating up most time within NSString init. So there is clearly something going on within NSString init, whoich I just would like to avoid happening - since I know already that I have valid UTF8 c-string taht I want NSString to init with. 15 x performance diff is too much.

Comment: @benjist Yes-- NSString is making copies of the strings that are being passed in and taking the slow path to do it, most likely converting it from the input encoding to UTF-16.   And, yes, in cases like these, reducing the memory bandwidth is almost always the most useful means of considering the problem exactly because it includes "reduce allocations", "reduce byte wise copies", and "reduce data transformations". And, in this case, using the allocations instrument (a memory quantification tool) and focusing on reducing the allocations, the memory traffic, is exactly how to solve the problem.

Comment: if you've read my comments and edits to the question, you'd see that I did my homework. I've located it to be __CFFromUTF8 and I've reasoned by checking the actual sources from Apple (see link) that this implementation is anything but optimized. Again, from all that you mentioned "reduce data transformations" is the heart of the problem, and the order of magnitude difference comes from Apple's implementation anything but optimal - for what I need it for (if you just need it to be as fast as possible).

Comment: @bbum Just won't to add that I have similar experience with creating NSString as benjist. NSString/CFString creation is really slow, and it is not coming from the allocation. NSString performs a number of checks, and other quite elaborate conversions. It may also have something to do with using *slow* ICU conversion routines, and these *are* slow: my own highly optimized Unicode conversion routines are in average 5 times faster when UTF-16 is involved. I believe, NSString creation can be made much faster.